# c/c++ correct format for arrays in function templates

Tags: c++, arrays, function, struct, format

not sure what to name this question, so forgive me if it sounds wrong or deceiving. im having an issue ive never before encountered. basically, when i have to put a struct into a function without creating the actual struct (only needing to use the values), i do it so:

```
struct a{
    int x,y,z;
};

void function(a x){ ... }

void main(void){
    function(a(34,64,75));
}
```

however, now i need to use an array inside that struct, so it looks like..

```
struct a{
    int x[5];
};

void function(a x){ ... }

void main(void){
    function(a(????));
}
```

and i have no idea how to initialize it properly without using an actual variable. just something inconvenient, but i would like to know the answer for this. ive tried searching and brute forcing my way, but i didnt do so well.

thanks for the help

EDIT: there are a lot of complications with my question that got many of the people upset with my inconsideration. firstly i am not referring to the c++ templates, but the actual meaning of the word, sorry for my broken english..
ill try to explain myself better (TRY): what i want to do is to omit the usage of creating a struct variable for the specific function and define the structs members myself manually in the calling of that function, as you can see in the first example..however, in the SECOND example, all im really asking is how to define members of said struct manually when they are in an array. once again i apologize for all my mistakes when first posting this question

Comment: ***`int`*** `main()`. Also, C **XOR** C++? There's no such thing as C/C++. Your tags say C, but templates are a C++ feature... now what?

Comment: What exactly is the benefit of using a struct instead of actual function parameters?

Comment: In C there is no such way. There are in C++, but while your title mentions C++ you haven't tagged your question with it, which is why I deleted my (C++ specific) answer.

Comment: Why do you need a struct for just one variable? Who says you're not creating the struct? You're just not keeping a reference to it

Comment: This is definitively not correct C. You can't just omit the `struct` keyword before the tagname as you would in C++.

Comment: I updated my answer. I am not sure if this answers your question however. If you want to avoid the struct and a just to need to use some numbers you can use the variadic template directly for the function or simply pass an array of numbers.

Comment: Thank you to jaap for *answering the damn question* instead of moralising in the comments.

Comment: @j_random It's not moralising (not a word), it's trying to understand the question and the real need behind it. If you were to ask a random hacking question you'd like us to tell you if the method you were inquiring about would get you thrown in jail wouldn't you?

Comment: thank you jaap, that covers it :~)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you use C++. If I understand your question correctly you want to initialize an array without using an intermediate variable. In that case you will need to add the appropriate constructor to your struct.

The following code will do this. However note you need a recent compiler, for example GCC version (>= 4.6), and you should compile as **g++ -std=c++11 file.cpp**.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <algorithm> 

using namespace std;

struct s{
  int x[5];
  // constructor 1. a variant using 'initializer_list'
  s(initializer_list<int> l) { copy(l.begin(),l.end(),x); } 
  // constructor 2. using a variadic template 
  template<class ...T> s(T... l) : x{l...} {} ;             
  // constructor 3. copy from an existing array 
  s(int* l) { copy(l,l+5,x);}
};

int f(s instance){ return instance.x[2]; }

int main(){
  s a1({1,2,3,4,5});      // calls constructor 1 (or 2 if 1 is left out)
  s a2{1,2,3,4,5};        // calls constructor 1 (or 2 if 1 is left out)
  s b1(1,2,3,4,5);        // calls constructor 2
  int l[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};    
  s c1(l);                // calls constructor 3

  cout << l[2] << endl;
  cout << a.x[2] << endl;
  cout << f(s(l)) << endl;
  cout << f(s{1,2,3,4,5}) << endl;    // calls constructor 1 again (or 2 if 1 is left out)
}
```